# Unable to clone repository from SCM server

Tags: git, networking, server, version-control, scmmanager

I created an SCM sever on one of my workstations and now I want to be able to clone repositories from this server on to my other workstations also connected to the same network, and eventually commit and push changes to the origin.
Problem is, when I try to clone the repo from the location shared by the SCM-manager, I get a "No route to host" message. I am able to ping just the IP alone though i.e. 192.168.1.172. Can you help me solve the problem?

Thanks
Tushar

[Repo information visible on SCM-manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaaFy.png)
[Trying to clone repo from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyknl.png)

Comment: 192.168.1.127 is in the [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) space. Your host needs to have a way to reach something in that space, and in your particular case, doesn't. Either scmmanager is handing out the wrong IP address, or something on your host is misconfigured. Given that you can ping it, it seems like a weird host network issue. (I would imagine the next debug step is to try to connect to other services on that IP address.)

Comment: When I get your snapshot right, you try to access SCM-Manager from another remote server, right? And you are able to ping the IP address from that server?
SCM-Manager takes the URL from the first request as its "Base URL". This may not always be correct, but SCM-Manager has no way to determine this on its own. If you want to "fix" this setting, you can do this in your case here under "Base URL Settings": http://192.168.1.172:8080/scm/admin/settings/general

Comment: Rene, I am not trying to access from a remote server but from another  system on the same network. Yes, I am able to ping the IP address from this system. I will look at the settings recommended by you and let you know.

Comment: @TusharBhattacharyya, you could check whether you can access the REST APi from that second system. If you run `curl http://192.168.1.172:8080/scm/api/v2` you should get a JSON response with a lot of further links. If you get an error or something else, SCM-Manager is not reachable with this URL from that system.